# How do I group data by a character?

Tags: r, grouping

when I try use `group_by(data, diet)` nothing changes to my data frame. I want it to have all the "C" observations first, and then all the "HFD", then all the "HFHS" and lastly the "HSD". Why is this not working?

Here is a sample of my data.

```
diet
<chr>
cage
<chr>
mouse
<chr>
amino
<chr>
1   C   61  3   16.85057
2   HF  58  3   16.67781
3   HFHS    66  3   16.42517
4   HF  65  1   16.53433
5   HS  63  1   16.30661
6   HF  58  2   16.63801
7   C   59  3   16.78098
8   HF  67  1   16.58652
9   HF  58  1   16.63393
10  HS  60  3   16.70945
```

Comment: Use arrange, not group_by.

Answer (score 0):

As deschen said in the comments, `group_by` doesn't do what you're trying to do. You can check with `help(group_by)`:

> `group_by()` takes an existing tbl and converts it into a grouped tbl where operations are performed "by group".

That function is kind of pointless on its own - it's usually a first step before a `summarise()` or a `mutate()` call.

You're trying to order a dataframe according to the values in a column. In `tidyverse`/`dplyr` we can do this with function `arrange()`:

```r
dplyr::arrange(data, diet)
```

Output:

```r
#> # A tibble: 10 x 4
#>    diet    cage mouse amino
#>    <chr>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1 "C   "    61     3  16.9
#>  2 "C   "    59     3  16.8
#>  3 "HF  "    58     3  16.7
#>  4 "HF  "    65     1  16.5
#>  5 "HF  "    58     2  16.6
#>  6 "HF  "    67     1  16.6
#>  7 "HF  "    58     1  16.6
#>  8 "HFHS"    66     3  16.4
#>  9 "HS  "    63     1  16.3
#> 10 "HS  "    60     3  16.7
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>